# Laravel get multple columns using distinct on one of them

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Face Table structure:

```
id
photo_id
person_id
```

A person can be in many photos. I want to return the first photo for each Person. I have tried:

```
$faces = Face::select('person_id','photo_id')
        ->groupBy('person_id','photo_id')
        ->whereNotNull('person_id')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

This returns the distinct combination, meaning all photos for each person. `Distinct` will only return the column I choose as distinct. I need both returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first photo per person to be returned, then group by the person only and return the minimum of the photo ids. In sql it looks like as follows:

```
select person_id, min(photo_id)
from yourtable
group by person_id
```

I'm not really great with laravel, but I make an attempt at how the query looks like there (you do not really need the person id is not null criterion):

```
$faces = Face::select('person_id',DB::raw('min(photo_id) as photo_id')
        ->groupBy('person_id')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```